using std::string_view and unique_ptr to manage memory from malloc()
I am using the GNU readline library, which returns a char *, allocated with malloc().
The user is responsible for releasing the memory with free().
I am thinking about using std::string_view and std::unique_ptr to work with this.
Is the following a good approach for a custom, move-only string view ?
class mystring : public std::string_view {
    std::unique_ptr<char, decltype([](auto *p) { free(p); })> up;

public:
    mystring &operator=(char *p) = delete;
    mystring(char *p) : std::string_view{p}, up{p} { }
};

...

char *buf = readline(prompt);
    if (!buf)
        return;

mystring s = buf;

Note that specifying a lambda for std::unique_ptr like this, requires C++20

The class is invalid. The operator=(char *p) results in a dangling pointer in std::string_view. Use std::getline in C++.

@3CxEZiVlQ I see.. The assignment operator isn't even necessary, so I'll explicitly delete it.

Public derivation from std types might be risky, also - view is generally a non-owning entity; your type is an owning one. I’d consider conversion operator or private string_view member instead.

Which readlline library? The GNU readline library?

what's wrong with std::string?

@Gene The idea is to manage the memory returned by readline(), not copy it to a std::string

The better idea would be not using readline(),

Classes from the standard library are (usually) not designed to be inherited from.  Also a string_view is a non-owning class but a view... and as such should never manage memory. So even if inheritance would be allowed (which is not recommended, since std::string_view doesn't have a virtual destructor).  You would violate two design guidines : "no surprises" and Liskov subsititution principle (your derived class does not behave as a string_view)

Micro optimisations like this are a world of hurt.  If you are dead set on using readline, write yourself a little utility routine that copies the returned value to a std:string, free what readline returns and then return aforesaid string.  Trust me, your future self will thank you for it.

@Tootsie -- The idea of managing the memory returned by readline(), rather than copying it to a std::string doesn't sound reasonable to me.

Please put the following into relation: how long does it take for the user to enter the next line? Seconds, at best, And how long does it take an average modern computer to heap allocate a small chunk and copy a line of data there? Typical experience shows that to be ~ 100µs, conservative guess. After that, you can still use string_view for parsing and further evaluation of the input.

Change public std::string_view to std::string_view so you have private inheritance.  That'll curtail polymorphic bugs, non-virtual destructor bugs, and slicing bugs.

@Eljay With private inheritance I lose the string_view interface, which was for me the most compelling reason to use inheritance.

You can using std::string_view::front; in your mystring.  Or any of the other string_view methods that want to expose.

Given the concerns about inheritance, I prefer to make custom types that provide the string_view via operator* and operator->. Similar to how std::optional works. Mimicking a smart pointer is reasonably elegant to use. Something like this: https://pastebin.com/BFbZamPW

If using operator* and operator-> to rummage for the wrapped type, that wrapped type could be expressed using private inheritance, or just as well (perhaps even a skosh better) as a member variable.
